# HTML5 History API just full load from index page

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

im trying to implement in a Java MVC (using Vraptor) the history api,

if you click in a link from /index, it will load the content in the #content div (its ok)

but when you type /content1 and press enter in the url bar, it only display the content1, without the menu

this pages is only for test, in a real env i will use a .js file:

index.jsp(access from /index)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#menu").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu");       
</script>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.jsp (can be accessed by /menu)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/content1"> Link 1</a>
<br>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/content2"> Link 2</a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

$('a').click(function() {

    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: "html",
       // beforeSend: function(xhr){
         //   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', 'true')
        //},
        success: function(response, status, xhr){
            $('#content').empty().append(response);
            history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl)
        }       
    });

    return false;
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the content1(can be accessed by /content1)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
content1
</body>
</html>
```

the content2.jsp (accessed by /content2)

its the same of content1, i just changed the 1 by 2)

how can i make when i load by writing in the url bar /content1 or /content2, and pressing enter, it load the /menu too? (full site, link from index, but in the page of the content1) if i write content2, load menu but displaying content2 in the #content?

Comment: Of course there is no menu, when only `/content1` is requested directly from the server – because there is no code whatsoever in that document for the menu. So put the menu code in there …

Comment: if i put menucode in /content1, i will get 2 menus when i load from index isnt it?

Comment: You could implement a check if the menu is already in the document (since you are only loading it using JS anyway). Or don’t serve full documents when the request is made via AJAX, but only the _actual_ body content. (Which makes more sense anyway, because what’s the point of using AJAX and the History API, if you are still sending _complete_ documents over the line each time? You could have had _that_ easier, by just linking to the documents in the first place without any AJAX …)

Comment: how is the other way without AJAX? i just see method using AJAX/PJAX, if i just link the document, it will load just the document, can you explain please?

Comment: _“if i just link the document, it will load just the document”_ – yeah, that’s how the web worked for a long time before AJAX – and the good news is, it _still does_. So what problem are you even trying to solve here by using AJAX …?

Comment: making it a better experience? imagine stackoverflow without it, facebook and etc... all this websites use something similar, just load the partial site, and of course, make sites faster

Comment: _“just load the partial site”_ – my point exactly … you are loading _complete_ HTML documents each time via AJAX, so the advantage is practically zero.

Comment: not according to this-> http://ntotten.com/2012/04/09/building-super-fast-web-apps-with-pjax/

and other sites, in first time you load full site, so in the next using pjax just partial site, understand?

Comment: That is the principle, yes – but you failed to actually implement this correctly. The only _new_ information in your shown `/content1` file are the title and the line of text in body – and yet, you are loading the _whole_ document … that this doesn’t improve anything much, should be quite obvious … Quote from the article you linked to: _“However, unlike a normal AJAX app that returns only data (JSON) from the server, a PJAX request actually contains normal HTML that has been generated on the server. **This HTML is only a fragment of the full page**”_

Comment: thats why i created the question, to someone help me implement this correctly =S!! i got what you mean, will not be "normal" to users write in url and press enter, but when they do, i want to display fullcontent, if they use the menu it will just load the information(partial) of the clicked link... you got what i mean?

Comment: Yes, but you are not getting me … Quote: _“Or don’t serve full documents when the request is made via AJAX, but only the actual body content.”_

Comment: yes i got, i will do the documents with just the body content, but since i cant make the full load when they enter by url bar, just the body is pointless yet, really i got you ;P, i can make my backend detect using the header when it come from index or out(so here it will load the menu again)

Comment: after a big time searching i got the sitemesh, i think it will supply me -_-